# Multiple highcharts on single page

Tags: highcharts

I am planning to design a single page application.
I am planing to do it using angularjs.
I want to display multiple charts on the same page.
Then I would like to generate a pdf report that  contains all charts on one page.
I also want to give an option to the user to select the no of row to be generated.(pagination)
I want this and everything else to be printed on a single page?
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to do this. What have you tried?

Comment: At the beginning I advice ot familiar with many similiar topics about multiply exporting.